# How to catch IndentationError

Tags: python, exception, indentation

First of all - I don't have a problem with bad-indentated code and I have an idea of how does this exception works like.

I ask, if there is any way to catch IndentationError in code with a try/except block? For example, let's say I'm writing a test for a function written by someone else. I want to run it in try/except block and handle all warning he/she could make. I know, that it's not a best example, but the first one coming to my mind. Please, don't focus on an example, but rather on problem.

Let's look at the code:

```
try:
    f()
except IndentationError:
    print "Error"

print "Finished"
```

The function:

```
def f():
  print "External function"
```

And the result is:

```
External function
Finished
```

And that's something, I'm ready to understand, becouse indentation in external function was consistant.

But when the function look like that:

```
def f():
  print "External function"
     print "with bad indentation"
```

The exception is unhandled:

```
    print "with bad indentation"
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Is there any way to achieve it? I guess that's the matter of compiling, and as far I don't see any possibility to catch. Does the `except IndentationError` make any sense?

Comment: Note that `IndentationError` is a subclass of `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. However, the function under test would have to live in a different module:

```
# test1.py
try:
    import test2
except IndentationError as ex:
    print ex

# test2.py
def f():
    pass
        pass # error
```

When run, this correctly catches the exception. It is worth nothing that the checking is done on the entire module at once; I am not sure if there's a way to make it more fine-grained.

Answer (score 9):

`IndentationError` is raised when the module is compiled. You *can* catch it when importing a module, since the module will be compiled on first import. You *can't* catch it in the same module that contains the `try/except`, because with the `IndentationError`, Python won't be able to finish compiling the module, and no code in the module will be run.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a tool such as [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857), which will analyse your module and report bad indentation, as well as many other errors.